# Calculation of longitudinal stress in a pipe segment

Tags: pressure, velocity, elasticity, stress-strain, metals

As part of a simulation model, I need to calculate the derivative of the longitudinal stress in a segment of a long thick-walled pipe. The pipe is vertical and submerged with the same fluid on the inside and outside. As part of modelling the pipe, it has been split in segments of length $l_j$, with a velocity $v_j$ at the segment outlet and $v_{j-1}$ at the segment inlet, i.e. if $v_j-v_{j-1} > 0$ the pipe will be lengthened, and stress will increase.
Until now we have modeled this as
$$
\frac{d\sigma}{dt} = E\frac{dv}{dz},
$$
where $z$ is the vertical position of the pipe, $\sigma$ is the longitudinal stress and $E$ is Young's modulus. In spatially discretized form this gives 
$$
\dot\sigma_j = \frac{E}{l_j}(v_j-v_{j-1}),
$$

where 
$$
\dot\sigma_jl_j = \int^{l_j}\frac{d\sigma}{dt}dz.
$$

This does only cover the longitudinal effects, and not the changes in stress that occurs if the pressure inside the pipe is increased.

The figure below shows one segment of this pipe, where $l=l_j$. From ["Roark's formulas for stress and strain"](http://materiales.azc.uam.mx/gjl/Clases/MA10_I/Roark's%20formulas%20for%20stress%20and%20strain.pdf), formulas for the strain of $a, b,$ and $l$ can be found for a given internal pressure with either free ends or capped ends.

[image: A pipe segment]

The change of volume or diameter is not of particular interest, but the longitudinal stress is of interest, used to calculate the speed $v_j$ of the segments in the pipe.

How can a system like this be modeled, and what is the equation for $\dot\sigma_j$?

An example case has the following parameters:
Total length, $L = 3000$ m,
$a = 0.1397$ m
$b = 0.1210$ m
Increase in internal pressure, p = $2.50 \cdot 10^7$ Pa
Poisson's ratio, $\nu$ = 0.3
Young's modulus, $E = 2.0 \cdot 10^{11}$ Pa

By using the equations in Table 13.5, case 1b, p.683 in "Roark's...", a lengthening of 0.4505 m for the whole pipe is obtained, but this does not describe a segment or the change in stress in a segment. A lengthening of more than 0.05 m for the whole pipe would be significant for our simulation, so our assumption is that increase in length due to pressure should be included in the model. If this assumption is wrong, a simpler model would be beneficial.

Comment: Is this a transient problem or a steady state problem?  If it steady state, why are you using velocities instead of displacements?

Comment: It is a transient/dynamic problem. I want to find the velocity of one end of the pipe when the other end of the pipe is moving for instance in a sinusoidal motion.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a liquid inside a pipe with a different pressure than outside the pipe?  You are applying an axial oscillation at one end of the pipe, and would like to know the axial oscillation at the other end.  Is the inertia (mass) of the pipe significant.  Are the varying  stresses exerted by the fluids on the inside and outside of the pipe considered significant?

Comment: Yes, there is liquid both inside and outside the pipe, and the pressure of the liquid inside may be higher than the pressure outside the pipe. I guess the inertia of the pipe would be significant, and in addition to the mass of the pipe, there is a lumped mass that is attached to the end of the pipe. I guess the shear forces of the flowing fluid outside and inside the pipe is of less importance, although they might have some impact. The main concern of this question is how the pressure difference between the outside and inside will affect the longitudinal stress.

Comment: There is an end cap to the pipe?  Is that the lumped mass?

Comment: In my judgment, you are starting out too complicated on this modeling job.  I would recommend starting out with a simpler version of the problem in which the fluid is not present (i.e., does not exert any transient stresses on the pipe).  I also recommend doing a differential force balance on the section of pipe between x and x + dx, taking into account the mass and acceleration of the material between these cross sections.  The equations should be couched in terms of the axial displacement u, rather than velocity.